# Add a map in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I want to add a js-map in **Django** admin (when you creating object).

I know about widgets, but how I understand, it must be connect to existing field (in model).

But I need a simple map (I have seen many projects like google map in admin, etc.) and they all use widgets and fields from model.

Now I use something like:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            widgets = {
                'address': MapWidget()
            }
```

And here you can see, that I use `address` - it is object attribute.

But I need only add map to admin page and not to connect this widget to model fields.

How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This helped me out for the same issue http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/django-admin-google-maps-location-picker-with-jquery/

Comment: @Newtt and how I can use `LocationField` in admin

Comment: Basically, create your Model with a separate field as type `LocationField`

Comment: @Newtt I described that I don't want to add some new fields in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class form(forms.ModelForm):
        address = forms.BooleanField(widget=MapWidget(),)
```